# Use non virtual methods in derived class C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, abstract-class, derived-class

I have an abstract Class Person and 2 derived Classes Customer and Employee. I store them in a list personList with the type Person* (list<Person*> personList). Now Customer has its own method int membershipFee and Employee has its own method int salary(). How can I iterate through them and get what is stored in membershipFee and separately in salary?

```
for(Person* pers : personList_){
    pers->memebershipFee();
}
```

doesn't work because class Person has not the method memebershipFee() and with

```
for(Customer* cust : personList_){
    cust->memebershipFee();
}
```

I got an error:

error: invalid conversion from 'Person*' to 'Customer*' [-fpermissive]

Comment: What is `personList_`? What is `Person`? What is `Customer`? Please [edit] your question to show us a [mre] (instead of attempting to describe the code).

Comment: This can likely be solved with a small change to `Person`.  Fixing code that we can not see is very difficult though.  A [mre] would likely get you an answer quickly.

Comment: Consider using `variant` if you don't want `virtual` interface in base class.

Comment: Storing customers and employees in the same place looks odd to me, and I can't think of any situation where it would make sense.

Comment: Its only an excercise not a real project 

Comment: I believe the question should be re-opened.  This is not a debugging question, but a question about implementing real world polymorphism concepts in C++.  Not the mechanics of `virtual` , grammar, or general code, but a common stumbling block in C++ designs.  @TonyDelroy gave some good answers to how to implement the desired behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a few choices, including:

- runtime polymorphism: you can add `virtual` functions to `Person` - `virtual int membershipFee() const` and `virtual int salary() const` - and have each derived class provide a suitable `override`, returning 0 if inapplicable.  This is probably ok for this situation as it isn't inherently nuts to think of customers having 0 salary and employees paying 0 membershipFee, but in other similar cases it can lead to *fat interfaces*, where objects have functions that don't even make sense to call on them.
- use `dynamic_cast`: `for(Person* pers : personList_) if (Customer* p = dynamic_cast<Customer*>(pers)) p->membershipFee();`.  This is generally considered a code smell, as larger programs that do this quickly become unmaintainable.
- using a visitor pattern ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern))

Comment: Ok this are 2 good ideas i will try this thank you vm.